# A better way to declare function name based on variable name?

Tags: python, flask, dynamic, routes

Lets say I have the function bellow:

```
@app.route('/foo', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def foo():
   print("food")
   return "OK"
```

I wanna have multiple functions based on variable name, this is how I achieved it:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)
methods = ['GET', 'POST']
names = ['foo', 'fubu', 'fomo', 'bar']
for name in names:
    exec(f"""
@app.route('/{name}', methods=methods)
def {name}():
    print('NAMED {name}')
    return '{name} - Example'
    """)
```

I have read that this way of using **exec()** is **highly discouraged** to be used and means I'm doing it all wrong if used,

Please whats the best ways to achieve since that approach is bad.

All I want to achieve is to have my app to accept additional JSON profiles that are stored in memory and contain all this instructions and load them if main admin enter the correct second long password upon edit.

#### PS: The app won't be getting any user inputs, and can be only modified by super admin.

Comment: It would be easier to explain what you're trying to achieve exactly because what do you mean by `additional JSON profiles`. Better explain how you'd actually use the thing you're trying to develop because it seems you're trying to solve a problem with a solution that isn't necessary

Comment: This looks so confusing. How does that register functions against a route?

Comment: @LoïcFaure-Lacroix I want to make the admin be able to add new routes without being hard-coded, i mean the admin can choose which modules to load, and route name, database model, also add code that will be executed inside that route ... **Second password must be provided for profile to be modified**

Comment: @roganjosh sorry, i have edited the question with an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments on the question:

> @LoïcFaure-Lacroix I want to make the admin be able to add new routes
>   without being hard-coded, i mean the admin can choose which modules to
>   load, and route name, database model, also add code that will be
>   executed inside that route ... Second password must be provided for
>   profile to be modified

I'd refrain you from doing that. Anyone with the right credentials would be able to execute code directly on the server and give pretty much all the credentials the user running the app has to execute anything.

You could use [compile](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#compile) with `exec` to generate code on the fly. Thought, I believe you're trying to achieve that for the wrong reasons.

If you want to be able to extend your application at runtime, you'd be better off with a plugin api in your application.

Something like this:

```
class MyPlugin(Plugin):
    def info(self):
        # return information about the module/plugin

    def register(self, application):
        # register the plugin into the application

    def unregister(self):
        # do cleanup
```

So each of your plugins could be defined as python packages that can be installed. Each of the python packages would in return expose an entrypoint or even namespace modules.

https://packaging.python.org/guides/creating-and-discovering-plugins/

When you get your entrypoint/module, you call the plugin class or simply methods for registering it.

All your main application has to do is discover the installed plugins and load/unload them at runtime.

The problem you'd have by executing code directly on the server is that it's not maintainable. You don't have any facilities to unload the changes you made and things will collapse sooner or later. Letting the python code compile is a huge security risk and if you can get away by installing manually a set of packages that can be discovered at runtime it's way safer and easier to manage.

Anything that is related to adding more routes can be done using API of the library you're using and anything related to adding profiles/databases etc. Can be done by storing configurations directly. There's virtually no reason to compile directly python code from within python code in 99% of the cases.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This has helped me grasp more information on how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

The name likely doesn't really matter. For example, you can do this:

```
def function_maker(name):
    def _():
        print(f'Named {name}')
        return '{name} - Example'
    _.__name__ = name
    return _
```

then

```
for name in ['foo', 'fubu', 'fomo', 'bar']:
    @app.route(f'/{name}', methods=methods)(function_maker(name))
```

There may be slight differences between something defined with `def foo():...` and `def _():...`, but none of them are likely to matter.

Comment: Thanks for this trick! One question please, is it possible to have certain code inside each function, without using exec()? I tried using specific text formatting inside the json which is going to be parsed then executed depending on conditions but it appears to be so lengthy and limited compared to exec().. any ideas?

Comment: It depends on what you are actually trying to do. For instance, the example shown here takes advantage of the fact that `_` closes over the variable `name`, so that the value of `name` at the time of the call is preserved in the `__closure__` attribute of `_`, even after the *name* `name` goes out of scope when the function returns. Basically, if you can handle the case where the JSON is passed as an argument to `_`, you can handle defining a function that uses JSON passed to `function_maker` by the same trick.

Comment: Just to note that the decorator is probably baggage/ambiguity here since Flask provides [`add_url_rule`](https://github.com/pallets/flask/blob/master/src/flask/app.py#L1107)